# Converting a user input to ASCII to set motor speed for Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Motor speed needs to be between 0-225 but when I enter a number between 0-9 the correct values don't show up from the equation. Sometimes even negative numbers appear.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("For DC motor, Enter F for Forward or R for Reverse");
  Serial.println("For DC motor, Enter 0-9 for speed");
}

void loop() {
  int command;
  command = Serial.read();
  updateMotor(command);
}

void updateMotor(int8_t command) {
  int8_t motorSpeed;
  if (command == 'F' || command == 'f') {
    Serial.println("You entered a direction of Forward");
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  } else if (command == 'R' || command == 'r') {
    Serial.println("You entered a direction of Reverse");
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  } else if (command >= '0' && command <= '9') {
    motorSpeed = (command - '0') * 255 / 9;
    analogWrite(6,motorSpeed);
    Serial.println("You entered a speed of: ");
    Serial.println(motorSpeed);
  }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of. I'm new to this stuff so go easy on me.

Comment: Because `motorSpeed` is a `int8_t`, it's maximum value is 127. So any digit above `'4'` will result in a negative number. Maybe you meant `uint8_t motorSpeed;`. But the best thing is to use the type of the second parameter of `analogWrite`, which apparently is an `int`.

Comment: you want `uint8_t motorSpeed`